# Laravel MongoDB unset use?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, unset, subdocument

```
   {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b609d6bd846108dc86433d"
    },
    "il": "Siirt",
    "ilce": "merkez",
    "ada": 466,
    "parsel": 1,
    "pafta": "M47-B-09-B-3-A",
    "tkgmkodu": "106478407",
    "tkgmeskikodu": [],
    "nitelik": "Tarla",
    "tapualani": "621,54",
    "cadde": "",
    "sokak": "",
    "mahalle": "",
    "kiracilar": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60b609d6bd846108dc86431d"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "adi": "kiraci Adı",
        "soyadi": "kiraci soyadi",
        "tc": "456454654654",
        "tel": "5424210910",
        "blok": "b",
        "kat": "5",
        "d-no": 18,
        "kayitTarihi": {
            "$date": "2017-01-14T21:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "cikisTarihi": "",
        "kiraTutari": 1000,
        "notlar": "",
        "borcAlacak": [{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "60b609d6bd846408dc86433d"
            },
            "tarih": {
                "$date": "2017-01-14T21:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "aciklama": "Ocak Ayı Borç Tahakkuku",
            "bankaKodu": "",
            "borc": 1000,
            "odeme": 0
        }, **{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "632609d6bd846108dc86433d"
            },
            "tarih": {
                "$date": "2017-01-15T21:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "aciklama": "Ocak Ayı Borç Ödemesidir.",
            "bankaKodu": "ObjectId",
            "borc": 0,
            "odeme": 1000
        }**]
    }],
    "mahkemeler": [""]
}
```

How I delete unset from MongoDB with Laravel use

Comment: Please show your effort by posting your current work/what you have tried.

Comment: @DUPi have you found your answer, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63277450/9471283

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what actually you use in laravel, but if you already have connection with mongoDB, you can delete it like this (using JS):

```
//replace with your id
let id_needed = '60b609d6bd846108dc86433d'
let deleted = req.db.collection('brands').deleteOne( { "_id" : ObjectId(id_needed)});
```